# PHP "round()" and numbers lower than 1.0

Tags: php, rounding

How come, when I round up decimals some numbers gets wrong

```
echo round(0.7125, 2);
```

Will result in: 0.71

BUT:

```
echo round(0.935625, 2);
```

Returns: 0.93999999

Why is that?

I´m using: 5.5.45-MariaDB

Comment: You pass `0` as number and want it rounded to `935625` place with the mode: `PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN`

Comment: I hope that you're not specifying numbers with a `comma` as the decimal separator

Comment: Shouldn't you use a "." as decimal separator?

Comment: PLease remove your "minus". There was actually a dot. Looks like PHPExcell changed it from coma to dot. My problem still remains!!!!

Comment: What's PHPExcel got to do with this? You made no mention of that in your original question

Comment: @MarkBaker no i didnt and it has no point in the question. the only thing i did was to write coma instead of dot. Becuase it´s a dot that goes into rounded!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>You are using a comma `,` instead of a dot `.` for the decimal separator. Use :</strike>

```
echo round(0.935625, 2); => 0.94
```

---

Ok it seems that this is an issue of floating point precision. You are asking the system to display `0.94` which the system can't represent as a `float`. So it displays the nearest number it can display: `0.93999999`

Comment: Sorry, the output was with a dot... not coma. Problem still remain!

Comment: @Tomas ok, i think i must read up on float than.. i dont understand. How can i solve this?

Comment: @Mjukis I suggest you a bit of reading about [Why Are Floating Point Numbers Inaccurate?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21895756/2307070)

Answer (score 1):

```
echo round(0.935625, 2);   // there is comma instead of .
```

Please remove comma `(,)` and try it

Comment: Sorry, the output was with a dot... not coma. Problem still remain!